# Perform text-processing task on remote server using shell variable specified on local machine

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, remote

I'm trying to write a shell script that proceses user information on a remote server via SSH. The user to be processed will be read interactively by the script.

- My current attempt looks like this

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Enter username which u want to add"
  read Student3
  ssh root@serverIP "useradd $Student3;"
  awk -F: '{print $1, $3, $6, $7}' /etc/passwd | grep "^${Student3}"
  ```

  and it creates empty output.
- Without the `grep` call, the output is

  ```
  root 0 /root /bin/bash
  bin 1 /bin /sbin/nologin
  daemon 2 /sbin /sbin/nologin
  adm 3 /var/adm /sbin/nologin
  lp 4 /var/spool/lpd /sbin/nologin
  sync 5 /sbin /bin/sync
  shutdown 6 /sbin /sbin/shutdown
  halt 7 /sbin /sbin/halt
  mail 8 /var/spool/mail /sbin/nologin
  operator 11 /root /sbin/nologin
  ```
- With the `grep` call appended as `| grep "^${Student3}"`, I get empty output.

Comment: You are adding a user to a remote server and then looking on your system if user is there ? Grep, by default, prints matching lines. Unclear what you want, try to put `ssh root@serverIP` before your awk command - you will have to work out how to escape `"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are expecting the user that you added to show up in the local `/etc/passwd`.  If it's the file on the *remote* system that you want to parse with `awk`, then you need to use `ssh` to access the data:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p 'Username: ' user

# Add user and check the remote /etc/passwd file
ssh remote "useradd '$user' && cat /etc/passwd" |
awk -F : -v user="$user" '$1 == user { print $1, $3, $6, $7 }'
```

That last pipeline could also be written

```bash
ssh remote "useradd '$user' && getent passwd '$user'" |
awk -F : '{ print $1, $3, $6, $7 }'
```

Note that you unlikely want to parse the `/etc/passwd` data with a regular expression like `^$user` as this would match any user with a username that starts with whatever string in `$user`.  The two variations of code above avoid this by not using a regular expression match and instead doing string comparisons of the complete username.